# JWT Token Validation in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt

I wrote Local Authentication Logic in Node, Generated a JWT and will send it to Angular App on Login.

In Angular, As soon as user Logs in with Correct Credentials, I then set the JWT in Local Storage!

In Angular I just check whether there is token in localStorage upon different route navigations. But how do I validate the token ??

If Iam changing the token from 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' to 'yyyyy' even then it's working since I am just checking whether there is token available in Local Storage.

How do I overcome this issue. ?

I knew about Headers. But those work only for API Calls, I simply want to restrict the user entering into protected Frontend Pages with invalid token.

Comment: We have been using this library for this purpose: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

Comment: For Securing API Calls, We need to send Token in Headers. So that Unauthorized user can't get into our API Calls. But, How do I secure entering them in to dashboard ??? Because If any random string set as token we will be entering into dashboard. How do I prevent this ??

Comment: what dashboard? And the library is specifically to check if a token is valid jwt-token.

Comment: The token is signed with a secret. So even if someone inject something it will still not be valid.   As to how to know if the session is valid. Information about validity is embedded in the format of a timestamp, which is checked.  Again. Changing the timestamp breaks the signing / validation process

Comment: Have a look at the passport modules and the jwt passport strategy.  Samples can be found on how to sign and how to check on client

Comment: @jcuypers What am talking about is let's say as soon as the user logs in we are setting token in localstorage like localStorage.setItem('token', someToken).

If some 'Y' user got to know the field is localStorage.token, He might set localStorage.token to some dummy value and access the frontend internal routes, Without JWT Validation. However the API Calls will fail since wrong token will be sent via headers to API's

Comment: You can set a route guard that checks that token is valid, with the library provided.